# How can i get the PHP magic constant __FILE__ work with Eclipse and PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Lately when i was debugging some PHP file with XDebug (under Eclipse on Ubuntu) i came across a strange behaviour:

```
print(__FILE__);
```

resulted in

```
"xdebug eval"
```

GEE!

So this magic constant seems **not** to work with this.

Anyone know a fix or a viable workaround? How to debug the debugger?
(Hardcoding a path is a PITA!)

Answer (score 9):

The output you get is not incorrect. `__FILE__` is a special constant that gets evaluated at parser time. When the PHP script gets compiled, it would really read something like this:

```
// test.php
<?php
    "test.php";
?>
```

even though the script source was:

```
// test.php
<?php
    __FILE__;
?>
```

This means that after parsing, there is no such "constant" `__FILE__` at all, as it has already been replaced.

This means that if you do in an IDE, through DBGp's `eval` command `eval -- __FILE__` it can **not** give you the `__FILE__` with any filename. Instead, it uses the filename for the current context which is `xdebug eval` or in later versions, `xdebug://debug-eval`.

In essence, it's the same as doing this:

```
php -r 'eval("__FILE__;");'
```

Which also outputs:

```
Command line code(1) : eval()'d code
```

Xdebug looks for this sort of format, and changes it to `xdebug://debug-eval` so that it can actually debug into eval'ed code.

`__FILE__` works as expected in PHP source code, as can be proven with this snippet:

```
<?php $far = __FILE__; // now evaluate $far in your IDE ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite this is quite old topic, but it is still actual. That's why I'm going to copy-paste my answer from the similar topic here as well.

This is XDEBUG issue, which can be fixed by downgrading (or upgrading in case you work with very old PHP) of XDEBUG version to 2.6.1.
I accidentally faced this issue and wasn't able to find an answer. Reinstall of server, PHP, PHPStorm, different versions of XDEBUG didn't help.
For MacOS one can use

`pecl install xdebug-2.6.1`

In case you already have newer version you can use command

`pecl uninstall xdebug`

Answers in [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001498520-xdebug-works-only-with-first-line) helped me a lot after several hours of investigation.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question. I solved by assigning it to a variable, then it works fine!

```
$file = __FILE__;
include dirname($file) . '/../whateverfile.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but you probably could use `__DIR__` in php 5.3.
UPD. Found that it often contains not what you expect it to.

Answer (score -1):

Create a breakpoint on line `print(__FILE__);` and analyse which variables are available to you.