# Xdebug weird __DIR__ constant

Tags: php, xdebug, magic-constants

I am writing an PHP CLI app which loads YAML files. When trying to do this within an Xdebug session:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../../foo/bar')
{
    /* ... */
}
```

`__DIR__` allways is `xdebug:` which will allways lead to `false` from `file_exists()`.

Is there any work around?

Comment: you're not running the code via `eval()` are you?

Comment: @Spudley No I am just executing the code "normally". When I don't use xDebug it works like a charm. But a non debuggable app isn't that nice :(

Comment: Hmm. If you were running via eval, the answer would be per [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924676/how-can-i-get-the-php-magic-constant-file-work-with-eclipse-and-pdt) (posted by the author of xDebug). It sure *sounds* like the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you do `$dir = __DIR__; if (file_exists($dir . '/../../foo/bar')...`?

Comment: did You figured out that?

Comment: nope didnt found anything

Comment: What is your PHP version ? `__DIR__` constant was introduced in PHP v5.3.0, see the alternative in my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

Set `$dir = __DIR__;` and use `if (file_exists($dir . '/../../foo/bar')`. It will work like that.

Comment: _Where_ do you set `$dir = __DIR__`? Is this still correct in xDebug 3?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your debugger shows you a wrong value as **DIR** has already been replaced in your script by the parser.

The whole explanation can be found here:

[How can i get the PHP magic constant __FILE__ work with Eclipse and PDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924676/how-can-i-get-the-php-magic-constant-file-work-with-eclipse-and-pdt)

> The output you get is not incorrect. **FILE** is a special constant that
>   gets evaluated at parser time.

Answer (score -5):

As an alternative replace your `__DIR__` constant with `dirname(__FILE__)` function

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../foo/bar')
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This does not work, `__FILE__` returns `xdebug://debug-eval`, not the correct file.