# PHP Xdebug Overrides __Dir__ and __File__ constant

Tags: php, xdebug

While debugging a PHP script using the "Listen for XDebug" in VS code(PHP Debug by Felix Becker extension), I found that the `__DIR__ and __File__` which are supposed to return the directory and the filename of the current running script are being overridden by Xdebug:

```
__DIR__ contains
"xdebug:"
__FILE__ contains
"xdebug://debug-eval"
```

However, if I assign the values to local variables, it works as expected.

```
$dir = __DIR__; // $dir holds the correct path, instead of "xdebug:"
```

This issue was encountered here [Xdebug weird __DIR__ constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254661/xdebug-weird-dir-constant).

However the post is old, and is missing resourceful explanation for the unexpected behavior.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you get is not incorrect. `__FILE__` is a special constant that gets evaluated at parser time. When the PHP script gets compiled, it would really read something like this:

```
// test.php
<?php
    "test.php";
?>
```

even though the script source was:

```
// test.php
<?php
    __FILE__;
?>
```

This means that after parsing, there is no such "constant" `__FILE__` at all, as it has already been replaced.

This means that if you do in an IDE, through DBGp's `eval` command `eval -- __FILE__` it can **not** give you the `__FILE__` with any filename. Instead, it uses the filename for the current context which is `xdebug eval` or in later versions, `xdebug://debug-eval`.

In essence, it's the same as doing this:

```
php -r 'eval("__FILE__;");'
```

Which also outputs:

```
Command line code(1) : eval()'d code
```

Xdebug looks for this sort of format, and changes it to `xdebug://debug-eval` so that it can actually debug into eval'ed code.

`__FILE__` works as expected in PHP source code, as can be proven with this snippet:

```
<?php $far = __FILE__; // now evaluate $far in your IDE ?>
```