# __DIR__ not resolved properly while debugging in Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug-3

I see that the [weird issue with **DIR** and Xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21254661/2223106) issue has been addressed, but am still confused.

Using php `v7.3` and Xdebug `v3.0.4`, I'm having a problem with a plugin that doesn't seem to be finding some Composer-managed dependencies in my Docker dev container and am hoping to use Xdebug to trace the issue.

However:

- `file_exists( __DIR__ . '/autoload-classmap.php')` is evaluating to false
- because `__DIR__ == "xdebug:"`
- and of course `false == is_dir(__DIR__)`.

In the Xdebug [functions docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions), it suggests ignoring a particular directory:

```
xdebug_set_filter( XDEBUG_FILTER_TRACING, XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE, [ __DIR__ . "/some/Dir" ] );
```

But `__DIR__` isn't a directory (evaluates as `xdebug:`). *Where* in the codebase is this filter supposed to go. Where is it that `__DIR__` is still a directory?

Would it be added to the configuration in the IDE somehow? I'm using VS  Code.

Comment: Please, edit your question and include the exact version numbers, just in case they are relevant for potential answerers.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying **your actual code** fails under XDebug, or just that **evaluating the expression in the debug console / watchlist** fails? Because [as the author of XDebug points out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251991/157957) you can't get a run-time value for a compile-time constant.

Comment: Actual code fails, with or without Xdebug. I think it’s failing to load an autoload file, which is pointed at via __DIR__. Tried assigning __DIR__ to a $var but still seems to show the runtime Xdebug value.